# error when Add a stub for a method using Mockito's 'when' API

Tags: flutter, mocking, mockito, tdd, flutter-test

Have this abstract class to get data from remote data source

```
abstract class NumberTriviaRemoteDataSource {
  /// Calls the http://numberapi.com/{number} endpoint.
  ///
  /// Throws a [ServerException] for all error code
  Future<NumberTriviaModel> getConcreteNumberTrivia(int number);
}
```

and have this abstract class for repository in domain layer

```
abstract class NumberTriviaRepository {
  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>> getConcreteNumberTrivia(int number);
}
```

bellow I created a test to implement `NumberTriviaRepository` class

```
@GenerateMocks([NumberTriviaRemoteDataSource])
void main() {
  late final NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl repository;
  late final MockNumberTriviaRemoteDataSource mockRemoteDataSource;
  setUp(() {
    mockRemoteDataSource = MockNumberTriviaRemoteDataSource();
    repository = NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl(
      numberTriviaRemoteDataSource: mockRemoteDataSource,
    );
  });
  group('getConcreteNumberTrivia', () {
    //to make test manageable create variables
    const tNumber = 1;
    const tNumberTriviaModel =
        NumberTriviaModel(text: 'test trivia', number: tNumber);
    const NumberTrivia tNumberTriviaEntity = tNumberTriviaModel;

    group('when device is online', () {
      test(
          'should return remote data when call to remote data source is successful',
          () async {
        //arrange                                
        when(mockRemoteDataSource.getConcreteNumberTrivia(any))  
            .thenAnswer((_) async => tNumberTriviaModel);               ---> Line *
        //act
        final result = await repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber);
        //assert
        verify(mockRemoteDataSource.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber));
        expect(result, equals(const Right(tNumberTriviaEntity)));
      });
    });
  });
```

bellow I implemented the `NumberTriviaRepository` class

```
class NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl implements NumberTriviaRepository {
  NumberTriviaRemoteDataSource numberTriviaRemoteDataSource;
  NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl(
      {required this.numberTriviaRemoteDataSource});
  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>> getConcreteNumberTrivia(
      int number) async {
    return Right(
        await numberTriviaRemoteDataSource.getConcreteNumberTrivia(number));
  }
```

and when run the test I get a `Mock.noSuchMethod` error :

```
MissingStubError: 'getConcreteNumberTrivia'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
getConcreteNumberTrivia(1)
```

with an explanation which is: "Add a stub for this method using Mockito's 'when' API, or generate the MockNumberTriviaRemoteDataSource mock with a MockSpec with 'returnNullOnMissingStub: true' (see https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/annotations/MockSpec-class.html)."

The problem is I created a stub method for getConcreteNumberTrivia at line *  but got error and don't have any idea how to fix this. By the way, I'm learning Clean Architecture using TestDrivenDevelopment so any comment would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setUpAll() to initiate mocks and use when in setUpAll section

```
@GenerateMocks([NumberTriviaRemoteDataSource])
@GenerateMocks([NumberTriviaLocalDataSource])
@GenerateMocks([NetworkInfo])
void main() {
  late final NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl repository;
  late final MockNumberTriviaRemoteDataSource mockRemoteDataSource;
  late final MockNumberTriviaLocalDataSource mockLocalDataSource;
  late final MockNetworkInfo mockNetworkInfo;

  const tNumber = 1;
  const tNumberTriviaModel =
      NumberTriviaModel(text: 'test trivia', number: tNumber);
  const NumberTrivia tNumberTriviaEntity = tNumberTriviaModel;
  setUpAll(() {
    mockRemoteDataSource = MockNumberTriviaRemoteDataSource();
    mockLocalDataSource = MockNumberTriviaLocalDataSource();
    mockNetworkInfo = MockNetworkInfo();
    repository = NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl(
      numberTriviaRemoteDataSource: mockRemoteDataSource,
      numberTriviaLocalDataSource: mockLocalDataSource,
      networkInfo: mockNetworkInfo,
    );

    when(mockRemoteDataSource.getConcreteNumberTrivia(any))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => tNumberTriviaModel);
  });
  group('getConcreteNumberTrivia', () {
    //to make test manageable create variables

    test('should check if the device is online', () {
      //arrange
      when(mockNetworkInfo.isConnected).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
      // act
      repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber);
      // assert
      verify(mockNetworkInfo.isConnected);
    });
    group('when device is online', () {
      setUp(() {
        when(mockNetworkInfo.isConnected).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
      });
      test(
          'should return remote data when call to remote data source is successful',
          () async {
        //arrange
        when(mockRemoteDataSource.getConcreteNumberTrivia(any))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => tNumberTriviaModel);

        //act
        final result = await repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber);
        //assert
        verify(mockRemoteDataSource.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber));
        expect(result, equals(const Right(tNumberTriviaEntity)));
      });
  });
}
```