# The GenerateMocks annotation contains a class which appears to already be mocked inline

Tags: flutter, mocking, mockito

I am following the ResoCoder Clean Architecture tutorial, which is not on par with the current package releases.

Currently I receive the error `Invalid @GenerateMocks annotation: The GenerateMocks annotation contains a class which appears to already be mocked inline: MockRemoteDataSource; use the 'customMocks' argument in @GenerateMocks to specify a unique name.` when I `flutter pub run build_runner build`

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockRemoteDataSource extends Mock implements CleaningJobRemoteDataSource {}

class MockLocalDataSource extends Mock implements CleaningJobLocalDataSource {}

class MockNetworkInfo extends Mock implements NetworkInfo {}

@GenerateMocks([CleaningJobRemoteDataSource])
@GenerateMocks([CleaningJobLocalDataSource])
@GenerateMocks([NetworkInfo])
void main() {
  late final CleaningJobRepositoryImpl repository;
  late final MockMockRemoteDataSource mockRemoteDataSource;
  late final MockMockLocalDataSource mockLocalDataSource;
  late final MocMockNetworkInfo mockNetworkInfo;
```

This follows the successful adaption of the first test case of this tutorial to the current Mockito version and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72228146/error-when-add-a-stub-for-a-method-using-mockitos-when-api) to a similar problem.

From the error message I would assume that I have already created a class with this name, but I cannot imagine where. Or I could imagine it is this `class MockRemoteDataSource extends Mock implements CleaningJobRemoteDataSource {}`, but this works in combination with `GenerateMocks` in a different unit test.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I don't know why the error message is referencing `MockRemoteDataSource`, but you have `@GenerateMocks([NetworkInfo])`, which will create a `MockNetworkInfo` class.  You already declared a `MockNetworkInfo` class a few lines before that.

Comment: Why do you have `class MockFoo extends Mock implements Foo {}` definitions at all?  You should be using `@GenerateMocks` for all of those classes. (Also, I don't know offhand if it matters, but typical usage would be to use `@GenerateMocks` with a `List` of all classes you want to mock instead of using `@GenerateMocks` multiple times.)

Comment: Basically because it works like this in another unit test. But so you saying - what I also was wondering - that both the above statement is in conflict and not needed. The other test has `class MockCleaningJobRepository extends Mock
    implements CleaningJobRepository {}

@GenerateMocks([MockCleaningJobRepository])` and is running

Comment: But removing those initial statements has lead to a successful build. And if I understand you correctly, no side effects from removing those lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But fortunately I was able to solve it.

I did the following:

1. Clean the project
   `flutter clean`
2. Get the packages
   `flutter pub get`
3. Remove all unused imports on the test file
4. Run build_runner
   `flutter pub run build_runner build`

It generated this file `[test file].mocks.dart`

I hope it works for you.

Comment: I'd love to add ```--delete-conflicting-outputs``` to ```build_runner``` command:             
 ```flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs``` IT fixes problems with conflict files if there are any. Hope it helps!